# How to use webVR API with RTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webvr

I am developed the RTC application, now we have added additional feature of VR,
How to integrate with real time scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I Found three.js , take photos from RTC and use that images by three js library that's orgin VR